# Converting a save File for GTA 5 Story from 360 to PC?

Tags: xbox-360, pc, grand-theft-auto-v

I have my 360 save on a flash drive, and have put it into Modio but I'm unsure what to do from there. I realize that the PC saves seem to have two types of files, and I've tried just making my file a .bak file but it didn't work.

Comment: `.bak` is just backup of a save, a simple copy with a different extension.

Comment: Do you know what the extension is of the regular file then? It just shows up as file on my computer.

Comment: what types of files does the PC save in?